# Tensorflow 1.5 build failing - missing path?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have been following a tutorial to install and build Tensorflow on macOS. When I attempt to build it, I use the following command:

```
bazel build --config=cuda --config=opt --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mpopcnt --copt=-maes --copt=-mcx16 --verbose_failures --action_env PATH --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH --action_env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

It fails almost immediately:

```
ERROR: /Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/numpy/BUILD:11:1: no such package '@local_config_python//': Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 291
        _create_local_python_repository(repository_ctx)
    File "/Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 255, in _create_local_python_repository
        _get_numpy_include(repository_ctx, python_bin)
    File "/Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 239, in _get_numpy_include
        _execute(repository_ctx, [python_bin, "-c",..."], <2 more arguments>)
    File "/Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 54, in _execute
        _fail("\n".join([error_msg.strip() if ... ""]))
    File "/Users/psmith/tensorflow/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 27, in _fail
        fail(("%sPython Configuration Error:%...)))
Python Configuration Error: Problem getting numpy include path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Is numpy installed?
 and referenced by '//third_party/py/numpy:headers'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: Loading failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.287s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (2 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core ... (2 packages)
```

I have tested and verified that numpy is actually installed. I have also forced an upgrade and a re-install. I can run Python3 > import numpy without error.

Comment: I was able to get past this error by adding the following to the bazel command:

    --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get past this error by adding the following to the bazel command:

```
--action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I actually got the error to go away by *removing* that from my .tf_configure.bazelrc. Evidently I ran bazel once before activating the custom python environment, and bazel cached the wrong python.exe location.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to verify the installation locations for your python and numpy builds. I'm installing for Python 3.7, so `which python3.7` tells me where the executable for python is, and running 

`import numpy as np
np.__file__`

within an interactive python session tells me where numpy is.

Having those in mind, enter the path to python and the appropriate site-packages directory when prompted during the process after entering `.configure`.

e.g., 

`Please specify the location of python. 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
Found possible Python library paths:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages`